# Basis/frame of reference for the coordinates of points in affine space $\mathbb{A}^n(k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, affine-geometry

I am currently reading a chapter on Affine Space from the Book titled "*Algebra, Topology, Differential Calculus, and Optimization Theory for Computer Science and Machine Learning*" ([link](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ejean/gbooks/geomath.html)) by Jean Gallier and Jocelyn Quaintance.

Sometimes, when talking about a point in an affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$ defined with a vector space $k^n$, where $k$ is a field, they use the coordinates notation. For instance, $u\in \mathbb{A}^n$ with coordinates $(u_1, \dots, u_n)$. Then they define the action of the vector $\boldsymbol{v}\in k^n$ with coordinates $(v_1,\dots, v_n)$ on the point $u$ by the equation: $$u+\boldsymbol{v} = (u_1+v_1, \dots u_n + v_n)$$
Is it fair to assume that in this case, the coordinates of $u$ are given by using the frame of reference defined as the origin of the vector space $k^n$? Because from my current understanding of affine space, defining the action of $\boldsymbol{v}$ on $u$ using that addition of coordinates will not work if the coordinates of $u$ are given by a frame of reference whose origin is different from the origin of $k^n$